# Reference point of "put" of picture environment

Tags: positioning, diagrams

Currently I use the `picture` environment to arrange graphics and text and I notice that the `put` command places the lower-left corner of the object at the specified position.

Now, I need to specify the positions of the lower-right corners of them. How can one do this?

Why do I need this?  I have a lot of images with the same specification except that they can extend leftward or upward but never rightward or downward. And I need to put a text label to the "same" position of each image.  Here the "same" means, "relative to the lower-right corner".

Comment: ``put(X,Y){\makebox(0,0)[br]{<<object>>}}`` ?

Comment: What objects are you using in `\put`?

Comment: @jfbu: That's it! Thanks. I guess I should write an answer to my own question?

Comment: @egreg: They are `\includegraphics{}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(moved from comment)

You could use

```
put(X,Y){\makebox(0,0)[br]{<<object>>}}
```

where `X` and `Y` are the coordinates and `<<object>>` stand for the "object" referred too in your question.